# Swift 2 Webview Load Delegate functions

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, swift2, uiwebviewdelegate

I'm trying to understand how can I make one Webview from a URL to know when it starts loading and when it finishes.
With the following code

```
class WebsiteViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       loadWebPage()
  }
func loadWebPage(){
        let theURL = "https://www.example.com/"
        let theRequestURL = NSURL (string: theURL)
        let theRequest = NSURLRequest (URL: theRequestURL!)
        webView.delegate = self
        webView.loadRequest(theRequest)
    }
    func webViewDidStartLoad(webView : UIWebView) {
        //UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
        print("Started")
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView : UIWebView) {
        //UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
        print("Finished")
    }

}
```

I've got these printed results

```
Started
Started
Finished
Finished
Started
Finished
Started
Finished
Finished
```

Any idea why??

Comment: does the url contain any redirects? You can try to print out webView.request?.URL in the delegate functions and see what you get

Comment: @NDoc no its only one

Comment: Are you redirecting from one link to another?

Comment: @mlidal its printing only the `https://example.com`

Comment: No there is no redirection

Comment: Maybe it's doing that when it loads `js` and `css` external files?

Comment: Where you have initialise webview? Make sure you have set WebView delegate once.

Comment: @SumeetBajaj the WebView Delegate is only once in my entire project. And the file that you see it is what it is! There is nothing else! One observation point is that if i set "https://google.com" it prints the correct order and time ` Started -> Finished`

Comment: I don't see webView variable to be declare or initialised. Can you share URL you are requesting.

Comment: @SumeetBajaj yes i forgot to paste it, although there is a variable called WebView... the URL is https://ledokosmos.gr/